# How do I turn this sequence into a sigma function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, notation

$$3\times2+1$$
$$ 3\times3+1$$ $$3\times3+2$$
$$3\times4+1$$ $$3\times4+2$$ $$3\times4+3$$
$$3\times5+1$$$$3\times5+2$$$$3\times5+3$$$$3\times5+4$$

And so it goes on for a number of terms dependent on the *n*-value, though exactly how it is dependent I'm not sure. You can leave the number of terms blank, as I'll figure that out myself. However, how I make this sequence into a sigma function I have no idea. Note that something like $(3\times k)(k-1)+\frac{(k-1)k}{2}$ will not work, because the terms are the individual operations, and not the bigger groupings: i.e., the last term doesn't need to be $3\times k + (k-1)$. The last term can be anything from $3\times k + (k-(k-1))$ all the way to the aforementioned one.

As such, the sequence becomes: 7, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, and so on.
So, any thoughts?

**EDIT:**

$$\sum_k^? \lceil \frac{n-x}{2} \rceil$$

"?" is something related to the *n*-value, and "x" is related to the *k*-value, and is somehow supposed to give the sequence. However, it appears that the current answers to this post give the answer for the objective of subtracting from "n" the entire sequence-parts, instead of the individual terms. As in, those answers make it so that "x" does this: $n - ((3\times4+1) + (3\times4+2) + (3\times4+3))$. However, "x" doesn't need to be all of that. The last "x" can be $3\times4+2$, the number added doesn't need to be k-1.

Answer (score 2):

This is a double summation since you have two sets of values (columns) which are increasing with conditions on each.

$$ \sum \sum 3\times a + b$$ should be the required form. Now, note that if you *fix* $a$, then the values $b$ go from $b=1$ upto $a-1$. For instance, if $a=4$ your terms are
$$ 3\times 4+1$$
$$ 3\times 4+2$$
$$ 3\times 4+3$$
You can update your sigma formulation as

$$ \sum \sum_{b=1}^{a-1} 3\times a + b$$

Finally, your $a$ values range from $2$ to $5$. Thus, the sigma formulation is

$$ \sum_{a=2}^{5} \sum_{b=1}^{a-1} 3\times a + b.$$

If you are looking for a general $k$-th term, it is possible but that requires triangular numbers $T(n) = n(n+1)/2$. The idea is that if $k$ is an integer with the property that
$$ T_n < k \leq T_{n+1}$$ then your general term is of the form
$$ a_k = 3\times(n+2) + (T_n-k).$$

Comment: But does this allow for individual separation of the terms? The way I see it, this is just a variation on $(3×k)(k−1)+\frac{(k−1)k}{2}$, or am I missing something?

Comment: It is a variation on  the expression you have written. Unfortunately individual separation is not possible since one of the variables is dependent on the other ($b$ above is dependent on $a$) and there is no single function like what you are looking for. $:($ I would love to see one myself.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. Does the double sigma function in the answer below also count as a variation of the same thing?

Comment: Yes, it is. Your introduction of the term $k(k-1)/2$ is my introduction of the triangular number $T_{k-1}$. The triangle number appears because as $a$ increases the variations in $b$ increases in accordance with $1,2,3,\dots$. So at the end of say $6$ $a$ values, you will have gone through $1+2+3+4+5+6$ terms.

Answer (score 1):

You can express this as a double summation:

$$\sum_{1≤n<m}^{n} \sum_{i=2}^m 3m+n$$

For example, when $m=4$, you get $3 \times 4 + 1, 3 \times 4 + 2$, and $3 \times 4 + 3$.

Comment: But does this allow for individual separation of the terms? The way I see it, this is just a variation on $(3×k)(k−1)+\frac{(k−1)k}{2}$, or am I missing something?

Comment: No, this is different. Basically, you are looping $n$ from $1$ to $m-1$, and then increasing $m$ by $1$, where the process repeats again. Think of it like a double for loop in programming.

Comment: So does this allow for cases where the last term does not add m-1 at the end, but rather anything from (m-(m-1)) to m-1?