# How do I turn this into a sigma function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3956104/how-do-i-turn-this-sequence-into-a-sigma-function) yesterday where I was being a bit too vague I believe. Here I have detailed it further, to show the proper trickiness with the task at hand.

The *n*-value starts at 8 and rises by one. I will show the different operations for the differen't *n*-values below.

$$\lceil\frac{8-(3\times2+1)}{2}\rceil$$

$ans=1$

$$\lceil\frac{9-(3\times2+1)}{2}\rceil$$

$ans=1$

$$\lceil\frac{10-(3\times2+1)}{2}\rceil$$

$ans=2$

$$\lceil\frac{11-(3\times2+1)}{2}\rceil + \lceil\frac{11-(3\times3+1)}{2}\rceil$$
$ans=3$
$$\lceil\frac{12-(3\times2+1)}{2}\rceil + \lceil\frac{12-(3\times3+1)}{2}\rceil + \lceil\frac{12-(3\times3+2)}{2}\rceil$$
$ans=5$

$$\lceil\frac{13-(3\times2+1)}{2}\rceil + \lceil\frac{13-(3\times3+1)}{2}\rceil + \lceil\frac{13-(3\times3+2)}{2}\rceil$$
$ans=7$

$$\lceil\frac{14-(3\times2+1)}{2}\rceil + \lceil\frac{14-(3\times3+1)}{2}\rceil + \lceil\frac{14-(3\times3+2)}{2}\rceil + \lceil\frac{14-(3\times4+1)}{2}\rceil$$
$ans=9$

$$\lceil\frac{15-(3\times2+1)}{2}\rceil + \lceil\frac{15-(3\times3+1)}{2}\rceil + \lceil\frac{15-(3\times3+2)}{2}\rceil + \lceil\frac{15-(3\times4+1)}{2}\rceil + \lceil\frac{15-(3\times4+2)}{2}\rceil$$
$ans=11$

$$\lceil\frac{16-(3\times2+1)}{2}\rceil + \lceil\frac{16-(3\times3+1)}{2}\rceil + \lceil\frac{16-(3\times3+2)}{2}\rceil + \lceil\frac{16-(3\times4+1)}{2}\rceil + \lceil\frac{16-(3\times4+2)}{2}\rceil + \lceil\frac{16-(3\times4+3)}{2}\rceil$$
$ans=13$

So, how do I make this into a sigma function? The answers given on the other questions didn't take into account negative numbers, meaning that the way it was set up would eventually lead to negative numbers decreasing the sum below its actual value (at least, that's how I understood those double sums).

Comment: Can you explain, how you generate those formulas?

Comment: @jojobo It's kind of hard, but the important thing is that the stuff subtracted from the n-value doesn't create a negative number. That's why I've ended up with the number of terms that I have. There are many instances where I could've taken the terms one or two steps further, without equaling a negative number but rather just zero. I didn't do that, but if perhaps the terms are taken to the max (without going from 0 to negative), a more transparent pattern will show.

Comment: Think I got it. Why dont you add the last part of n=16 to n=15 with switching 16 to 15? Because its positive: 15-(3*4+2)=1>0.

Comment: @jojobo Oh snap, it was supposed to have that term from the get go. As long as it produces a positive answer, it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following works: 
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor} \sum_{j=1}^{min(k-1,n-3k-1)} \lceil \frac{n-(3  k+j)}{2} \rceil$$

**Explanation** 
The outer sum follows from your $3 \times k$, because you have every $k$ from $2$ to $\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor$ at least one time in your summation. The inner sum then takes a $k$ and shows which numbers you add behind the $3k$-term. In your summation you have two rules: \

1. The fraction has to be positive. Therefore the upper summation bound is $\leq n-3k-1$, which gives $\frac{n-(3k+j)}{2} \geq \frac{n-(3k+(n-3k-1))}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$. Every greater $j$ would make it $\leq 0$.
2. The added term $j$ has to be less than $k$. Therefore the upper summation bound is $\leq k-1$.

Comment: Does it help you?

Comment: Hey, I've only tried on number so far (just came back from dinner). Your equation worked for an n-value of 12, though I am quite new to double sigmas. I will try a few others and let you know. It looks promising right now though. One question: If a negative number receives a floor function, will it go closer to 0, or further away from 0? If the former, then this works, if the latter, then it doesn't work for 12. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Hey, I re-checked 12, and I don't think it works actually. My double sigma calculation was off the first time, but I looked over it again now and I think it adds to negative numbers at the end. $\lfloor \frac{12-(3\times4+1)}{2}\rfloor $ equals 0, which is fine, but  $\lfloor \frac{12-(3\times4+2)}{2} \rfloor$ =$-1$ and  $\lfloor \frac{12-(3\times4+3)}{2} \rfloor$ =$-2$

Comment: Yes, I see the problem.

Comment: Now it should work.

Comment: Interesting, I will check it out now :) I see you changed from floor function to ceiling function, any particular reason behind that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117532/discussion-between-jojobo-and-a-kvale).

Comment: This is brilliant, it has worked for every n-value so far! (I tested a lot)